# Delete specific cookie with Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

I need to delete a specific cookie from a website. At first I have tried several ways to delete ALL cookies, however none of them worked properly (not all cookies were deleted).

I also tried the below code to find the cookie I need to delete, but I can't figure out how to delete it after found it.

Can anyone help?

```
function getCookie(name) {
            var dc = document.cookie;
            var prefix = name + "=";
            var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
            if (begin == -1) {
                begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
                if (begin != 0) return null;
            }
            else
            {
                begin += 2;
                var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
                if (end == -1) {
                end = dc.length;
                }
            }

            return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
        } 

        function deleteCookie() {
            var myCookie = getCookie("dropin_date");

            if (myCookie == null) {

            }
            else {
                // if cookie exists delete it
            }
        }

        deleteCookie();
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out.

```
function accessCookie(cookieName) {
    var name = cookieName + "=";
    var allCookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<allCookieArray.length; i++)
    {
      var temp = allCookieArray[i].trim();
      if (temp.indexOf(name)==0)
      return temp.substring(name.length,temp.length);
      }
    return "";

}

var delete_cookie = function(name) {
   document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
};    

var mycookie = accesCookie('test');

if(mycookie != ''){
   delete_cookie('test');
}
```

In order to delete a cookie set the expires date in the past. it will delete automatically

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to work only if the "Expires / Max age" column value is "Session". When the value of this column contains specific date, it won't erase it. An example of the date is "2021-06-15T16:29:48.107Z"

Comment: it should not be a problem. I can delete whatever cookie just with that function. I have already test it by my computer. it works. take a deep look at the code.

Comment: I am sure you tested it, however on my site it won't work and I can't figure out why.

Comment: dont worry. try to use an api from mozilla they have a good tool for handle your task. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework

Comment: have you tried to delete it manually  then try to create and use the functions above.

Comment: Yes I can delete it manually from DevTools, but there are specific cookies that I can't delete with Javascript for no reason...

Comment: should be a good idea if you send me a screen shoot of yours cookies by inbox

Comment: Yeah I will do so... Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I found you on chat but I am not able to start a chat with you. Is there another way?

Comment: look at me by facebook stopplissss